# Prompt engineering GPT for numerical scores?

Tags: gpt, prompt-design

**Background:** I am currently working on an NLP project using GPT 3.5 via the OpenAI python API.
Engineering good prompts seems to be the most critical part of my pipeline so far. Crucially I have long input texts, for which I want to get numerical sentiment scores for a variety of different questions in a ZERO SHOT setting.
There are many possible applications such as predicting nuanced scores on different aspects (plot, acting, staging etc) of a theatre show from a long detailed review; or the sentiment of a twitter response to a new political policy (emotional objections, economic objections, moral objections).

**Question:** What is best practice to extract reliable numerical sentiment scores from GPT models?

**What I've tried:** Looked for guidance on the [OpenAI cookbook](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/main/techniques_to_improve_reliability.md)  and explored many associated links. It seems like existing suggestions for sentiment scoring usually use embeddings in a setting where a small number of labelled samples are available. Following heuristics from various prompt engineering sources I have used a pipeline of iteratively asking for detailed summaries and then more concise summaries culminating in a single sentence and finally a score. This has yielded impressive results; indeed I suspect such a 'prompt-pipeline' may yield more sophisticated sentiment scores than fine-tuning approaches, unless one has the luxury of extremely large amount of labelled data.
However, converting these final sentences to numeric scores is still somewhat unreliable. I couldn't find specific advice online.
What is best practice?

Comment: something like this? https://github.com/microsoft/guidance

Answer (score 2):

To address converting the final sentences to numeric scores being unreliable, you could use `logits_bias` to restrict the model to only predicting certain tokens.

You can use [OpenAI's tiktoken library](https://github.com/openai/tiktoken) to find token IDs:

```
enc = tiktoken.encoding_for_model("gpt-3.5-turbo")
print([enc.encode(x) for x in "1234567890"])
# [[16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [15]]
```

Integers up to "999" are each represented by a single token, higher numbers and decimals get split up into multiple tokens.

Then, using the OpenAI Python API, adding a bias of 100 will [ensure exclusive selection](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/5247780-using-logit-bias-to-define-token-probability) of one of those tokens:

```
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    engine="gpt-35-turbo",
    messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "How many fingers are on a hand?"}],
    temperature=0,
    max_tokens=1,
    frequency_penalty=0,
    presence_penalty=0,
    stop=None,
    logit_bias={16: 100, 17: 100, 18: 100, 19: 100, 20: 100, 21: 100, 22: 100, 23: 100, 24: 100, 15: 100}
)
print(response["choices"][0]["message"]["content"])
# 5
```